# how to write a wrapper class for sigc++?

Tags: c++, events, class, libsigc++

would like to have a central place to register new signals, connect to signals, and so on. now i thought to use sigc++. however, i don't know how to code a wrapper class for this template based lib. something along the lines of:

```
class EventManager {
public:
    ... singleton stuff ...
    template<typename ReturnType, typename Params>
    bool registerNewSignal( std::string &id )
    {
        sigc::signal<ReturnType, Params> *sig = new sigc::signal<ReturnType, Params>();

        // put the new sig into a map
        mSignals[ id ] = sig;
    }

    // this one should probably be a template as well. not very
    // convenient.
    template<typename ReturnType, typename Params>
    void emit( id, <paramlist> )
    {
        sigc::signal<ReturnType, Params> *sig = mSignals[ id ];
        sig->emit( <paramlist> );
    }

private:
    std::map<const std::string, ???> mSignals;
};
```

what should i replace the ??? with to make the map generic, but still be able to retrieve the according signal to the given id, and emit the signal with the given paramlist -- which i don't know how to handle either.

Comment: I think this singleton design has several problems, for example you have to take care of synchronization issues (e.g. protect mSignals with a mutex) and potential race conditions.
Why not use the sigc++ directly?

Comment: i need a central management point for events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a base class which have emit() function:

```
template<class Ret>
class SigBase {
public:
  virtual Ret emit()=0;
};
```

and then some implementation of it:

```
template<class Ret, class Param1>
class SigDerived : public SigBase<Ret>
{ 
public:
  SigDerived(sigc::signal<Ret, Param1> *m, Param1 p) : m(m), p(p){ }
  Ret emit() { return m->emit(p); }
private:
  sigc::signal<Ret, Param1> *m;
  Param1 p;
};
```

Then the map is just pointer to base class:

```
std::map<std::string, SigBase<Ret> *> mymap;
```

EDIT: It might be better if the SigBase doesn't have the Ret value, but instead only supports void returns.

Comment: well yes, that would work. however, this implementation has to be provided by the client who shouldn't be bothered to do this in the first place. he is supposed to use my EventManager to register and fire the events.

Comment: wouldn't your register function just do it? It can do all the work internally.

Comment: yeah, i could take a pointer to the new signal. the point is, that the client shouldn't be bothered with implementing this in the first place.

Comment: I didn't get it why client would implement this instead of your eventmanager implementation?

Comment: because i can't say upfront what kind of signals the client want to use.

Comment: Well, the implementation above works with any kind of signals... You just need separate Derived classes for each kind of signal, and maybe register function needs to be overloaded...

Comment: i'd need another implementation in case the signal has two parameters, and another for three, and ... you get the idea?

Comment: yup, the same thing happens inside sigc library. It has used signal0<void>, signal1<void, int>, signal2<void, int, int> etc. It's just the nature of functions that it can have several parameters. The c++0x has some better support for this case, but without it, you can just write several classes with different names.

Comment: template<typename ReturnType, typename Params>
  sigc::signal<ReturnType, Params>* get( const std::string &id )
  {
   SignalMap::const_iterator it = mSignals.find( id );
   if ( it == mSignals.end() )
    return 0;

   return static_cast<sigc::signal<ReturnType, Params>*>( (*it).second );
  }

Comment: geez, sorry for the formatting :) ... i wrote a template method, and return the signal to the client. she, then, can call emit with as many params as the signal was created with. dunno how and if that'll work. will have to test it.

Comment: the getter is not going to work very well, if you add more than one type of signals to the map... Basically you can only return the base class pointers.

Comment: the signal is casted before it goes out, however, i think this is ugly as hell, and quite error prone; as the user could give wrong signal signature for the given id, and then ... BooOOoom!

Comment: accepted your answer, as it's the best and safest way to implement it. however, i've removed the central point of management, and added some predefined signals to the objects.

Answer (score 0):

here's what i have so far. it works ... but feels like an abomination. how could i improve it further? for instance, how to get rid of the reinterpret_cast?

@dimitri: thanks for the tip with the mutex, i'll add that.

```
class Observer {
public:

    static Observer* instance()
    {
        if ( !mInstance )
            mInstance = new Observer();
        return mInstance;
    }

    virtual ~Observer() {}

    template<typename ReturnType, typename Params>
    sigc::signal<ReturnType, Params>* get( const std::string &id )
    {
        SignalMap::const_iterator it = mSignals.find( id );
        if ( it == mSignals.end() )
            return 0;

        return reinterpret_cast<sigc::signal<ReturnType, Params>*>( (*it).second );
    }

    template<typename ReturnType, typename Params>
    bool registerSignal( const std::string &id )
    {
        SignalMap::const_iterator it = mSignals.find( id );
        if ( it != mSignals.end() ) {
            // signal with the given id's already registered
            return false;
        }

        // create a new signal instance here
        sigc::signal<ReturnType, Params> *sig = new sigc::signal<ReturnType, Params>();
        mSignals[ id ] = reinterpret_cast<sigc::signal<void>*>(sig);

        return true;
    }

private:
    Observer()
    {
    }

    SignalMap           mSignals;
    static Observer*    mInstance;
};

Observer* Observer::mInstance = 0;
```

Comment: @tp1: any ideas as to how c++11 could help me here?